# Multi Select Statement Stored Procedure in SQL Server2008

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I created following Store procedure whose return

```
Create PROCEDURE GetData (@Year varchar(20),@Month varchar(20), @Workcell varchar(100))
AS
BEGIN
declare @StageName varchar(50)
declare @Amount bigint
declare @Stages table(Stage varchar(100))
create table #ResTable (Stage varchar(100),Amount bigint)
 select Distinct(Stage) into #Stages from Stage_Skill_Matrix

while exists(select * from #Stages)
begin
 select top 1 @StageName = Stage
from #Stages
select top 1 @Amount =Amount from Stage_Req_Master where Month=@Month and Stage=@StageName and Workcell=@Workcell

insert into #ResTable values(@StageName,@Amount)
end
select * from #ResTable

END
GO
```

After executing this Stored procedure I am expecting StageName and Amount from Temporary table ResTable that is Stages and their Amount.

Rather when I execute the SP through Right Click->Execute Stored Procedure, it does not show me anything. It just goes on executing but I can see 40row affected in Message Window but no rows in Result window

Comment: aren't you getting any error, as I don't see any declaration of #Stages? there is @Stages but not #Stages.

Comment: No, But when I use    create table #Stages (Stage varchar(100)) then I get error while altering the Stored Procedure "There is already an object named '#Stages' in the database."

Comment: But I can not find Stages table anywhere in database

Comment: In end of the sp you have to drop the temp table #stages.If you check tempdb then you will see this db there.

Comment: Can you please elaborate, how to check tempdb? Can you add the lines to above example.

Comment: Database > System Database > tempdb > Temporary Tables

Comment: I can view #ResTable there but coudn't able to open the same. While right click, it has only two options reports and Refresh. and on query "select * from #ResTable" it shows Invalid Object Name "#ResTable". same with "select * from ResTable". Also Stored Procedure dont even complete, it goes on and I have to stop it manually.